# Log4net to log method name

Tags: logging, log4net

I want to log the method where my Log method is being called.
The [Docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) says that we can use %method to log the calling method

> method
>
> Used to output the method name where the logging request was issued.
>
> WARNING Generating caller location information is extremely slow. Its
> use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.
>
> See the note below on the availability of caller location information.

I tried the same and its just giving me  Question mark

> 2016-03-30 22:44:28,609 [9] INFO  ? Test
>
> 2016-03-30 22:45:48,059 [9] INFO  ? Test

Is it not working or it's depreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if %method should work. However to log the caller method name you can use an extension method with a CallerMemberName attribute. This would work something like:

```
public static void InfoWithCaller(this ILog logger,string message,[CallerMemberName]string memberName = ""){
    logger.InfoFormat("Caller: {0}, "+message, memberName);
}
```

And is probably more efficient then the %method method if you can get it to work.